# How to delete all users in Airflow?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, airflow

I am setting up web authentication for Airflow web server. I added a few users following the guidance of the official guide. Now I want to delete all users that have been added, what should I do?

I have tried to

```
session = settings.Session()
session.delete(user)
```

, but it does not work. Even if it works and it will only delete one user at a time.

Maybe I should regenerate the SQLAlchemy user table?

Comment: If you're thinking to reset the db, do just use the airflow cli command for that.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are calling `session.commit()` afterwards to commit the transaction. If you want to delete all users at once, try `Session.query(User).delete()` instead. Also note that you can delete through the Airflow UI under `Admin > Users`.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can do it in CLI:

```
airflow users delete -u aramis
```

just copy this 100 times and change the `username` with all users you have, then paste it into CLI.

`-u` is username